# Insert or update a number of determinate products

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have create the following table:

```
  Create table products (
        code             varchar2(9),
        group_code       varchar2(9),
        name             varchar2(30),
        price            number,  
        CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

How to make a trigger that only allowed to have three names of different products grouped by group code

### Examples:

For example if I have:

> Two apples (apple1,apple2)  GROUP1
>
> One carrot (carrot1) GROUP1
>
> One **pear** (pear1) GROUP1

- I can add another ***pear***(pear2), for example ,but if I try to add a
  *melocoton*, Oracle should give an error.
- I can do that the next update: update products set name='pear' where code='apple1';
- But, I can not do: update products set name='watermelon' where
  code='apple2';

I have heard that using triggers per row oracle give problems in *updates*

Comment: Seems like that logic should be higher up in the stack than a database trigger unless it causes a data integrity problem. Can you not enforce that higher up the appication stack?

Comment: So i can use a package? @DStanley

Comment: search for compound triggers.

Comment: You could add a `group_number` that is declared as an integer with a check constraint that limits it to the values 1, 2, & 3 and put a unique index over `code` and `group_number`. You'll need to maintain the `group_number` value, but it would at least give you declarative RI that guarantees your data integrity.

Comment: You can also create another table for allowed products and enforce a foreign key constraint to your main table.